# Glassfish takes ages to restart

Tags: java, glassfish

I created a domain in Glassfish 4.01, and deployed an app which is working fine. However when I try to restart the domain (with `asadmin restart-domain -v`) the process is very slow. I spends 5 minutes on the line

```
[#|2014-10-14T19:02:28.056-0400|FINE|glassfish 4.0|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol|_ThreadID=120;_ThreadName=pool-13-thread-1;_TimeMillis=1413327748056;_LevelValue=500;ClassName=org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser;MethodName=awaitTermination;|
Await iterating at 1413327748056 waiting for 2|#]
```

Then when it gets over it, it spends ages on lines which all look like this

```
[#|2014-10-14T19:08:26.113-0400|FINE|glassfish 4.0|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.autodeploy|_ThreadID=106;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;_TimeMillis=1413328106113;_LevelValue=500;ClassName=org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployedFilesManager;MethodName=getFilesForDeployment;|
Skipping /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/bundles because its name is in the list of files to ignore|#]
```

and it goes on for at least 10 minutes, I don't even know if it eventually gets to an end. The first server start just took 10 seconds, so there must be something wrong here.

I also tried to delete the content of the folders /applications, /autodeploy, /osgi-cache. Now it gets stuck at

```
[#|2014-10-14T19:33:31.576-0400|FINE|glassfish 4.0|org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=FelixStartLevel;_TimeMillis=1413329611576;_LevelValue=500;ClassName=HK2Main$HK2ServiceTrackerCustomizer;MethodName=addingService;|
registering service = org.apache.felix.cm.file.FilePersistenceManager@75a34889, contract = org.apache.felix.cm.PersistenceManager, name = null|#]
```

Do you have any idea of why all of this happens, and how to solve it?